# How to enable the PDO driver for sqlite3 in php?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, xampp

My SQLite is version 3.4.0:
[image](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/05/30/03/33/3822461_343x44.jpg)

However my phpinfo's PDO support for SQLitev3 is not enabled/listed:
[image](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2009/05/30/03/32/3822444_630x115.jpg)

How can I enable it? I installed my web server via XAMPP.

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.2.9. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the PDO driver for sqlite3 is called 'sqlite', so you already have it installed. The sqlite2 driver is older.

> PDO_SQLITE is a driver that
> implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO)
> interface to enable access to SQLite 3
> databases.
>
> In PHP 5.1, the SQLite extension also
> provides a driver for SQLite 2
> databases; while it is not technically
> a part of the PDO_SQLITE driver, it
> behaves similarly, so it is documented
> alongside it. The SQLite 2 driver for
> PDO is provided primarily to make it
> easier to import legacy SQLite 2
> database files into an application
> that uses the faster, more efficient
> SQLite 3 driver. As a result, the
> SQLite 2 driver is not as feature-rich
> as the SQLite 3 driver.

From http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

Answer (score 12):

Go to your `php.ini` file and search for "sqlite". These are probably commented:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

Uncomment them, and restart Apache.

Comment: you can found `php.ini` file location using command `php --ini`

Answer (score 1):

"pdo_sqlite" and "sqlite3" are different extensions and are loaded in `php.ini` in different lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue on a linux/unix system with the following lines added in php.ini :

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```