# add sqlite to laravel 10 project

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I created a migration and after that, I changed the environment file connection to sqlite I let only the DB_CONNECTION
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
after that, I ran the command php artisan migrate and it said there is no SQLite database would you create it i typed yes and it showed this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

could not find the driver (Connection: SQLite, SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:829
  825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
  826▕                 );
  827▕             }
  828▕ 
➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
  830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
  831▕             );
  832▕         }
  833▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
  PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
  PDO::__construct("sqlite:C:\laragon\www\GrafikartLaravelTuto\database\database.sqlite", [])
```

it said that there is no sqlite driver but the driver is there in the config database.php file
'connections' => [

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable the PDO driver for sqlite3 in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929585/how-to-enable-the-pdo-driver-for-sqlite3-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Is the sqllite PHP extension enabled?
If you are running Laragon, look for pdo_sqlite under PHP -> Extendions
Else, look in php.ini: extension=pdo_sqlite