# could not find driver (Connection: sqlite, SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

Tags: laravel

Don't know what the problem is:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (Connection: sqlite, SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
    809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    810▕                 );
    811▕             }
    812▕
  ➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(
    814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    815▕             );
    816▕         }
    817▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct()

Script @php artisan migrate --ansi handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Register the Composer autoloader...
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...
(require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleRequest(Request::capture());
```

Comment: What are you using? `SQLite`? Did you install the PHP driver? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929585/how-to-enable-the-pdo-driver-for-sqlite3-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve it if you are on Windows you can go to the following link:

[How to enable the PDO driver for sqlite3 in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929585/how-to-enable-the-pdo-driver-for-sqlite3-in-php)

And if you use GNU/Linux you just have to open the terminal and write the following:

```bash
php --ini
```

With that command you will see where the "php.ini" file is located, in my case it is in the path "/etc/php/php.ini".

We open the text editor as root user and look for the following in the "php.ini" file:

;extension=pdo_sqlite

We remove the dot and like ";" to uncomment and then we look for:

;extension=sqlite3

And we also remove the semicolon ";" To uncomment, we save it and run again:

```bash
php artisan migrate
```

And then you can run the command without problems:

```bash
php artisan serve
```

But to summarize, in both operating systems you must search for that file to correct the error, I hope it works for you.